# What's the radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ about $z=i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

The solution booklet says it's $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|a_k|}{|a_{k+1}|}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|(1-i)^{-k}|}{|(1-i)^{-k+1}|}=|1-i|=\sqrt{2}.$$ I can't see why this limit doesn't evaluate to $\frac{1}{|1-i|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ Is there a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: Should probably be $-(k+1)$ in the exponent in the denominator

Comment: $z=2$ gives $-1$ LHS but a divergent RHS, so its not unique

Comment: Once you have learned a bit more complex analysis, there will be no need to use the ratio test.  The function $f(z)=1/(1-z)$ has only one singularity, at $z=1$, and the distance of this from $i$ is $\sqrt2$.  This is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series for $f(z)$ about $z=i$.

Comment: @Lorago That seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: @David As it happens the question continues "Explain how you could have gotten this answer by considering the singularities".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very elementary solution.$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{(1-i)-(z-i)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{(1-i)(1-(\frac{1}{1-i})(z-i))}$$ $$=\frac{1}{(1-i)(1-(\frac{1+i}{2})(z-i))}$$. Thus, upon expanding in powers of $(\frac{1+i}{2})(z-i),$ the series converges for $$\Vert (\frac{1+i}{2})(z-i)\Vert <1$$ i.e. $$\Vert z-i \Vert<\Vert \frac{2}{1+i} \Vert$$ $$=\sqrt 2$$